# Built-in TextBox validators in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, validation

In ASP.NET MVC 3 I can use a set of special validation attributes, to have a client-side and server-side model validation.

Is there anything similar provided by silverlight out-of-the-box for TextBox control? If I want to check if the Silverlight text box user has been editing is empty, do I need to implement this logic myself?

Comment: As far as I remember, if you bind a double or datetime property to the text box and enter a random string - it will display the validation error related to the convertation. But the validation rules for empty values you should write yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of attributes in the [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) namespace that can be used for validation.  These attributes are applied to the view-model property that you bind the Text of the TextBox to.

These attributes don't do any server-side validation, but that might not be too much of an issue.  You can sidestep client-side validation in ASP.NET MVC (or any web application for that matter) by disabling JavaScript in the browser.  However, it's much trickier to sidestep the validation in your Silverlight application - disabling the Silverlight plugin would disable your entire Silverlight application.

Comment: It may be my understanding of English is "not performing well", but are you sure your answer is relevant to the question: "Is there a built-in validation mechinism in Silverlight TextBox Control"?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov: I believe my answer is relevant.  The validation isn't in the TextBox control itself, but in the vast majority of cases you will be binding the Text property of the TextBox to a property in your view-model layer, and this property can have the attributes I mentioned.  If you don't think this answer is relevant, please explain why not.

Comment: I agree. Just wanted to make sure you understood my question correctly. Verifying the view model/model properties with attributes is indeed independent of the UI layer. Thank you for your answer and a comment.